# Selenium: NoClassDefFoundError WebDriverException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In some (seemingly random) cases, I get below error when working with Selenium and Chrome headless webdriver:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException`

I guess some elements are not available in the browser which causes the exception but without an exception message I cannot be sure.

I have this in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-alpha-7</version>
</dependency>
```

I can create a dummy instance of WebDriverException in my code. So what can be the problem?

UPDATE:
I have also seen other types of Selenium exception with no messages. This is another example with stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:196)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:129)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:123)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:501)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:238)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:79)
```

Comment: Any reason why you chose an unstable version?

Comment: I remember there was an issue when I started working with Selenium which was fixed in v4. Remembered it: I needed access to DevTools

Answer (score 1):

`WebDriverException` class is part of the **Selenium API** distribution. That dependency is missing from your POM. Aside from that, unless you are doing an evaluation, stay away from alpha versions. Always use stable releases.

Comment: Added that, but still get the same exception without any additional information.

Comment: @Mahdi update your post with the exact stack trace if you can. The more info, the better.

Comment: @Mahdi, also, just in case, if you are running this from Eclipse, right-click on your project top folder and under "Maven" submenu, click on "Update Project".

Comment: I added another example with stack trace. And also I'm using IntelliJ